# How to add data as content in a razor script for 2sxc?

Tags: 2sxc

I want to import data from a third-party module into 2sxc as *content* within a razor script.

```
   IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetData () 
   {
   ...
   }

   var data = GetData();
   App.Data.Create ("ContentTypeName", data);
```

The code above imports data into the App, but it is not linked to a content block. How do I create a new content block or access the current content block and link that data to it?

Answer (score 0):

Requires a bit deeper knowledge of how Content items get attached to a module instance. There are good articles and docs on that. The key is understanding ContentGroups, so in a View, you are inside a module, and therefore your ContentGroup can be accessed like this (2sxc v9.43.x code, it may be different after ~v10.25.x):

```
  var cGroups = App.ContentGroupManager.GetContentGroups();
  var cgGuid = Dnn.Module.ModuleSettings["ToSIC_SexyContent_ContentGroupGuid"];
  System.Guid cgG = Guid.Parse(cgGuid.ToString());
  ContentGroup myCG = App.ContentGroupManager.GetContentGroup(cgG);

  <p>My ContentGroup has @myCG.Content.Count() Entities</p>
```

Hopefully that gives you enough to search on and figure out from there.

Also, if you want to do it manually, that is what the Replace and Add Existing (blue 2sxc buttons) do. They show you ALL the items in the ContentType and give you to option to add an existing slot/item or replace the current item in it's slot.

Comment: I am using 2sxc v11.07.03. The module setting is still there, though App.ContentGroupManager is gone.